# Why am I getting "interface conversion: interface is int32" for converting a list integer element to a string?

Tags: list, go

New to Go...I wrote a program to remove duplicate integers stored in a list.  When I run the following test for the removeDuplicates function, I get the following error which points to this line: *testString += strconv.Itoa(e.Value.(int))* in *linked_test.go*.  Why is this and how do I fix it?  I store integers in *testList* and fetch them with e.Value and typecast with *.(int)*.

```
panic: interface conversion: interface is int32, not int [recovered]
    panic: interface conversion: interface is int32, not int
```

**linked_test.go**

```
package linked

import (
    "container/list"
    "strconv"
    "testing"
)

func TestDuplicates(t *testing.T) {
    var (
        testList           = list.New()
        exampleList        = list.New()
        testString  string = ""
    )
    testList.PushBack(1)
    testList.PushBack(2)
    testList.PushBack(3)
    testList.PushBack(2)
    exampleList = removeDuplicates(testList)
    for e := exampleList.Front(); e.Next() != nil; e = e.Next() {
        testString += strconv.Itoa(e.Value.(int))
    }
    if testString != "123" {
        t.Fatalf("removeDuplicates failed")
    }
}
```

**linked.go**

```
package linked

import (
    "container/list"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func removeDuplicates(l *list.List) *list.List {
    var newList = list.New()
    var dupString string = ""
    for e := l.Front(); e.Next() != nil; e = e.Next() {
        if strings.Index(dupString, strconv.Itoa(e.Value.(int))) == -1 {
            dupString += strconv.Itoa(e.Value.(int))
        }
    }
    for _, c := range dupString {
        newList.PushBack(c)
    }
    return newList
}
```

Comment: In addition to [OneOfOne's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31498076/55504), abusing the string representation of integers like this is silly, slow, and won't work (e.g. {123, 12} --> "123" --> {1, 2, 3}). If you want fast duplicate detection you want a set type which in Go usually means a map. E.g. with a `var m map[int]bool` and then something like `m[e.Value.(int)] = true` in the loop and finally `for v := range m { newList.PushBack(v) }`.

Comment: thanks Dave, great point.  I'm so new to static typed languages & Go that I'm grasping at straws at times, just trying to do anything I can to speed up the learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rune` is aliased to `int32`,

```
for _, c := range dupString {
    newList.PushBack(c) // c is a rune aka int32
}
```

is pushing `int32`s, while `int` is aliased to `int64` on 64bit CPUs, so one way to do it is to just force the type:

```
for _, c := range dupString {
    newList.PushBack(int(c))
}
```